# Why to use "pass" instead of an empty line?

Tags: python

When is it necessary to use `pass` if it is possible to leave an empty line or even do not have a statement?

For example:

```
# print "x is greater than y" if x is greater than y

x = 3
y = 8

if x > y:
    print("x is greater than y")
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Did you try using an empty line here?

Comment: There is a third option: drop the `else:` part altogether.

Comment: `pass` is needed only if you have to leave a *suite* empty. `else:` takes a suite (1 or more statements). But you don't need the suite in the first place if you just leave out the `else:`.

Comment: You cannot use an empty line in python.

Comment: @rockikz, sure you can. There are at least two valid empty lines in the code above. It's just that in certain cases, `pass` is required if there are no other statements as Martijn described.

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's what I actually meant, he cannot leave that `else` clause just empty.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I understand that to have an empty line I should remove the `else` statement (I meant this "or even do not have a statement?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doc](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html): `pass` is a *null* operation - when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed, for example:

```python
def f(arg): 
    pass    # a function that does nothing (yet)

class C: 
    pass    # a class with no methods (yet)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Python's syntax requires some kind of explicit token for a no-op statement.  Languages with curly-brace statement delimiters can use `{}`.  Python uses `pass`.

Comment: Thanks, Batchelder!